# How to add elements to a list?

Tags: javascript

I'm able to add items to my list but my issue is that I can't keep a **specific timeStamp** for each item added. Basically if I add items I want this to show:

```
05/03/2018 12:44:13 - item 3

05/03/2018 12:44:10 - item 2

05/03/2018 12:44:04 - item 1
```

But my code keeps showing the **same TimeStamp** for all the items. can anyone tell me what I'm missing please? Thanks in advance!

Here's my code:

[**PLUNKER**](https://ng-run.com/edit/QDLmDRHb7uzVBUaEWmIM?open=app%2Fapp.component.html)

```
  <div *ngFor = "let alert of alertList">
        {{currentTimeStamp +' - '+ alert }}
  </div>
```

Comment: you probably want an alert.timeStamp, currently you just have one hence it's always the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the timestamp, along with the message, in an alert object when the alert is created. Like this:

```
  onSave(){
    this.alertList.splice( 0 , 0 , { 
      'message': this.alertEntered,
      'timestamp': (new Date(Date.now())).toLocaleString('en-GB', { hour12:false } ).replace(',','')
    });
  }
```

And render it like so:

```
  <div *ngFor = "let alert of alertList">
        {{ alert.timestamp +' - '+ alert.message }}
  </div>
```

Edit: [PLUNKER](https://ng-run.com/edit/Lcw1dhV9wJ3iSAPCPrxx)